# How to let the main thread end after the child thread ends itself in C++? (Windows)

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, exit, thread-local

There is a main thread whose execution content CANNOT be controlled due to special irresistible reasons, **that is, it has no ability to process any messages sent by child threads including events**.

This main thread will create a child thread using `windows-api` `_beginthreadex`. This child thread that can perform any operation creates a form and is responsible for handling the windows message loop.

This child thread has a `thread_local` object. The destructor of this object must ensure that it is called, and this object is obtained like this:

```
obj_t get_tl_obj () {
    thread_local obj_t tl_obj__;
    return tl_obj__; // Copy constructor, not reference
}
```

If it is the return of the main thread, I can send a message to the child thread in the destructor of a global variable and wait for the child thread to end normally.

```
    ::PostMessage (hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    ::WaitForSingleObject (taskhandle, 1024);
```

However, if the user closes the program by clicking the close button, the child thread will receives `WM_CLOSE` message and will release the window. At this point, I want the child thread to force the main thread to close.

I try to call the `exit` function directly, but in this way, although it can end the main thread and call the global destructor at the same time, the child thread itself is also forced to close, which will make the destructor of the `thread_local` object unable to be called.

So, I want to know, how can the child thread force the main thread to close after the child thread ends itself? Or do I need to create a thread specifically for this?

Comment: Note that `_beginthreadex` is rather antiquated these days. Consider using [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead. Or go directly to the actual WINAPI thread primitives (which `_beginthreadex` is really a wrapper around).

Comment: Sidenote: Identifiers containing two consecutive underscores are reserved and may not be used as names in declarations.

Comment: In general, most main threads are held in a loop checking if it's time to quit, often by checking if window threads have ended.

Comment: Use events to synchronize between Win32 threads: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-event-objects

Comment: Does the primary thread wait for the secondary thread to terminate? @som If you're using the CRT you'll want to perform the CRT's per-thread initialization. That's what `_beginthreadex` is for. It isn't any more *"anitquated"* than using the Windows API thread primitives directly. It's just generally more correct.

Comment: *that is, it has no ability to process any messages sent by child threads including events.* - and what is mainthread doing ? why it can not handle any "signals" ?

Comment: "how can the child thread force the main thread to close". There is no way to force a thread to close. (The thread might be holding a global lock, and forcing it to close would orphan the lock and probably result in data corruption.) You have to get the threads to cooperate somehow.